# Commandlets from a custom Module not being recognised

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have a custom Powershell module I have been working on for the past few days, I am now trying to integrate it into powershell as a module that always gets auto loaded.

My module is placed under the  `C:\Users\...\Documents\PowerShell\Modules` , which is one of the places Powershell expects modules from.
This is the structure for the module:

```
C:\Users\...\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\MetaData-System\MetaData-System.psm1
C:\Users\...\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\MetaData-System\MetaData-System.psd1
```

The  `MetaData-System.psd1` files contents are:

```
@{

ModuleVersion = '0.0.1'

GUID = '9e976eac-1010-4e0b-95e4-76c8bfc1ece1'

Author = '...'

CompanyName = 'Unknown'

Copyright = '(c) .... All rights reserved.'

FunctionsToExport = @( 'Set-Metadata', 'Clear-Metadata')

CmdletsToExport = @()

VariablesToExport = '*'

AliasesToExport = @()

PrivateData = @{

    PSData = @{

    }

}

}
```

The  `MetaData-System.psm1` files contents consists of two functions called `Set-MetaData` and `Clear-MetaData`.
In  Terminal running `Get-Module -ListAvailable` lists:

```
Directory: C:\Users\...\Documents\PowerShell\Modules  
  
ModuleType Version PreRelease Name PSEdition ExportedCommands  
---------- ------- ---------- ---- --------- ----------------  
Manifest 0.0.1 MetaData-System ... {Set-Metadata, Clear-Metadata}
```

But when I try to use one of the functions from the module by typing "Set-Met" no autocomplete occurs, neither do any parameters get suggested. If I write  it all down such as:

`Set-Metadata -path "C:\Users\...\Documents\test.txt" -Flags "Hello World`

I get this error:

```
Set-Metadata: The term 'Set-Metadata' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.  
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I have searched everywhere to see what I am doing wrong and
out of ideas now.

I have taken the liberty to cross post this question on other forums as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: As suggested by @Abraham Zinala, I tried `Get-Module`:

```
ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Manifest   0.0.1                 MetaData-System
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Content, Clear-Content, Clear-Item, Clear-ItemProperty…}
Manifest   7.0.0.0               Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object…}
Script     2.1.0                 PSReadLine                          {Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadLineOption, Remove-PSReadLineKeyHandler, Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler…}
```

No commands are present for the `MetaData-System` module.

Comment: Might sound like a silly question but, did you run a new PowerShell instance, or have you imported the module into your current session? Can you run `Get-Module` by itself and see if it shows in the returned output? Specifying `-ListAvailable` will list available modules instead of **loaded** modules, so without it, the command should output the current modules loaded in memory.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, not silly at all. I manually restarted terminal several times and did try the import-module command, still facing the same issue. I also downaloded a module called `PSWriteHTML` from Powershell gallery just to see its folder structure and its `.psd1` structure, they are identical to my folder structure and `.psd1` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [module manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Module_Manifests) is missing the following entry:

```
RootModule = 'MetaData-System.psm1'
```

This is necessary for the implementing script module file (`*.psm1`) to be discovered.

In the absence of it, it is only the *manifest* file (`.psd1`) that is discovered, and the *implementation* of the exported commands is effectively missing.

This is evidenced by your sample [`Get-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-module) output listing the `ModuleType` as `Manifest` rather than `Script`.

Comment: The guide I was following did not mention this key, Thanks allot for bringing my attention to the manifest page. All Commandlets and Parameters are there now. it feels so much better than I expected. So happy now :]

Comment: Glad to hear it, @hellen_dorandt89; my pleasure.